# Strange fluent nhibernate mapping for legacy application

Tags: asp.net, .net, oracle, fluent-nhibernate

We have a legacy ASP.Net project which we are currently refactoring with the MVP pattern.
For the backend we are using Fluent NHibernate with an oracle database.
The previous developers had a strange localization implementation directly in the database.
And we have a hard time to map it with fluent nhibernate.

We have following tables, which are in separate databases. (oracle schemas)

```
db1.Activity
(
  ID,               (pk)
  ID_LANGUAGENAME,  (fk)
  INPUT_DATE,
  and so on...
) 

db2.LanguageName
(
  ID,               (pk)
  ID_LANGUAGE,      (pk)
  NAME
)

db2.Language
(
  ID,
  LANGUAGE,
  LANGUAGE_SHORT
)
```

The ID_LANGUAGE is stored in a the ASP.Net session variable.
I want to map the entities so that i can do something similar like this query.

```
SELECT LN.NAME, A.INPUT_DATE FROM db1.Activity A
INNER JOIN db2.LanguageName LN ON A.ID_LANGUAGENAME = LN.ID
INNER JOIN db2.Language L ON LN.ID_LANGUAGE = L.ID
WHERE A.ID = :ACTIVITYID AND L.ID = :LANGUAGEID_FROM_SESSION_VARIABLE
```

So basically i wan't an Activity entity that looks like this:

```
public class Activity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime InputDate { get; set; }
}
```

Where the name of the Activity get's automatically mapped to the proper LanguageName.Name field in the database.
Is this even possible with NHibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way

```
<filter-def name="LanguageFilter">
  <filter-param name="activeLanguage" type="System.UInt32"/>
</filter-def>

<class name="Activity">
  <id name="Id"/>

  <many-to-one name="NameHolder" column="ID_LANGUAGENAME"/>

  <property name="InputDate"/>
</class>

<class name="ActivityName" tble="LanguageName">
  <id name="Id"/>

  <property name="Name"/>
  <filter name="LanguageFilter" condition=":activeLanguage = ID_LANGUAGE"/>
</class>

public class Activity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    protected virtual ActivityName NameHolder { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name
    {
        get { return NameHolder.Name; }
        set { NameHolder.Name = value; }
    }

    public virtual DateTime InputDate { get; set; }
}
```

And Query

```
// at the beginning of the request
s.EnableFilter("LanguageFilter").SetParameter("activeLanguage", Session["Language"]);

var activity = session.QueryOver<Activity>()
    .Where(a => a.Id == activityId)
    .Single();

Console.Writeline(activity.Name);
```

Comment: This kind of works, but when i map the LanguageName to the Activity as a Reference relation (1 to 1) i sometimes still get an NHibernate exception stating that there are multiple languagenames with the given id. So it seems that the filter does not always applies. Should i set the parameters of the filter globally or for every repository that i implement?

Comment: the filter must be set on every ISession created because it is applied only to that. Also if the languageId would be static per application run, it could be set on mapping level which would make it even easier.